# POW Error - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack-pow

For some reason, one of my apps won't work with pow.

I set the symlink fine...to my app, and the app shows up as linked.

```
curl get.pow.cx | sh
cd ~/.pow
ln -s ~/desktop/rails_project/myaccountdeck/myaccountdeck
```

But then I get this error:

```
Error: unknown process error
Error: unknown process error
    at Process.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/process.js:116:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/process.js:3:63)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:367:14)
```

The weird part is, localhost works and my other apps work...

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: So `rails s` works fine? You don't get any errors in the log? Others have experienced something similar here: https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/30

Comment: rails s works totally fine.  must be a database issue, thanks for pointing me toward a right direction.  will post if find cause.

Comment: it turns out active_admin had a conflict with Pow

Comment: I too have had issues with active_admin and Pow. Specifically, there seems to be an issue with my registered active admin resources that aren't in plural form. Meaning, if I have a resource called "user" it will prevent pow from serving. If I rename it to "users" everything is fine. Anybody else seen this? It seems inconsistent, sometimes it's not an issue. Right now I can only use old fashion `rails s`.

Comment: I had a similar issue following an upgrade to OS X Yosemite and it turned out to be related to Postgres. This is a helpful thread if that's what led you here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970132/pg-tblspc-missing-after-installation-of-os-x-yosemite

Comment: You may want to consider to mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 8):

It was pointed out in the comments, but to make it perfectly clear: In case of errors like this

```
rails s
```

is your friend. It will run your app using WEBrick (instead of pow) and you will almost certainly see errors that prevent your app from starting up (as console output).