# `pg_tblspc` missing after installation of latest version of OS X (Yosemite or El Capitan)

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I use postgres from homebrew in my OS X, but when I reboot my system, sometimes the postgres doesn't start after the reboot, and so I manually tried to start it with `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`, but then the error occurred with the following message: `FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory`.

The last time it occurred, I couldn't get it to the original state, so I decided to uninstall the whole postgres system and then re-installed it and created users, tables, datasets, etc... It was so disgusting, but it frequently occurs on my system, say once in a few months.

So why does it lose the `pg_tblspc` file frequently? And is there anything that I can do to avoid the loss of the file?

I haven't upgraded my homebrew and postgres to the latest version (i.e. I've been using the same version). Also, all the things that I did on the postgres database is delete the table and populate the new data every day. I haven't changed the user, password, etc...

EDIT (mbannert): 
I felt the need to add this, since the thread is the top hit on google for this issue and for many the symptom is different. Homebrewers likely will encounter this error message:

```
No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

So, if you just experienced this after the Yosemite upgrade you now you're covered for now reading this thread.

Comment: Eep, it really, really shouldn't! When you say "latest version", please show the exact version number. Also, have you put any tablespaces on external storage? where's the PostgreSQL data directory located?

Comment: Also, `pg_tblspc` is a *directory*. The only way I can see this directory and just this directory randomly vanishing is filesystem corruption or a particularly badly behaved virus scanner or file sync tool.

Comment: I don't have any virus scanner. I don't know what `tablespaces` is, so I don't think I put it on external storage.

Comment: Hm. All I can tell you is that something's *badly* wrong. `pg_tblspc` does not just disappear on any system I've ever encountered, nor can I imagine a sane reason it would. It's going to be very hard to say what makes your system different without a lot more detail.

Comment: What I've done on my postgres is 1) select one database, 2) delete the entire data on the DB, 3) populate the new data to the DB, 4) push it to heroku. This procedure is done every day. Do you think that pushing it to heroku DB is something related?

Comment: "select one database", "delete the entire data on the db". Details?

Comment: Ah, sorry that was wrong. I did all the procedure above on my MySQL system, and then copy the mysql database to the corresponding postgres database using `py-mysql2pgsql`(https://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql)

Comment: OK, well, that seems unlikely to be related, it's just using PostgreSQL's client libraries or generating an SQL script. You'd have to mess directly with the data directory to create the problem you're encountering.

Comment: Then is the OS upgrade relevant? I use Yosemite beta right now, but I'm not sure when it occurred previously. I've updated it whenever the new beta is available (totally 6 or 7 times I think).

Comment: Beta operating system? Yeah, that's probably a candidate for the issue. Perhaps you should raise this with Apple, you might've found a bug. Again, nearly impossible to say without detailed investigation and the ability to actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this @Gardecolo?  I'm having the same issue after upgrading to Yosemite.

Comment: @Donovan, no. I've uninstalled and re-installed it. I do never think I should do, but I had to recover it as soon as possible because I use it for my business...

Comment: @CraigRinger Don't know about the beta testing at Apple inc., but the release version of Yosemite still has the issue. Enfin, came here and problem solved.

Comment: I wrote a blog entry following up on this and another issue after researching the issue some more. Overall I simply cannot believe how Apple has handled this. http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/ware-yosemite-possible-postgresql-upgrade-issues-os-x-10-10/

Comment: Has anyone managed to find out what in OS X is doing this yet? It's crazy behaviour.

Comment: I have a custom installation path under $HOME, one day I thought I would clean up all empty directories and this happened during the next PostgresSQL restart. Empty directories are not useless after all.

Answer (score 937, accepted):

Solved... in part.

Apparently, Installing the latest versions of OS X (e.g. Yosemite or El Capitan) removes some directories in `/usr/local/var/postgres`.

To fix this you simply recreate the missing directories:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_commit_ts
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_dynshmem
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_logical/mappings
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_logical/snapshots
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_replslot
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_serial
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_snapshots
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_stat
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_stat_tmp
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_tblspc
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_twophase
```

Or, more concisely (*thanks to [Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761771/nate)*):

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/{{pg_commit_ts,pg_dynshmem,pg_replslot,pg_serial,pg_snapshots,pg_stat,pg_stat_tmp,pg_tblspc,pg_twophase},pg_logical/{mappings,snapshots}}
```

Rerunning `pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/postgres` now starts the server normally and, at least for me, without any data loss.

**UPDATE**

On my system, some of those directories are empty even when Postgres is running.  Maybe, as part of some "cleaning" operation, Yosemite removes any empty directories? In any case, I went ahead and created a '.keep' file in each directory to prevent future deletion.

```
touch /usr/local/var/postgres/{{pg_commit_ts,pg_dynshmem,pg_replslot,pg_serial,pg_snapshots,pg_stat,pg_stat_tmp,pg_tblspc,pg_twophase},pg_logical/{mappings,snapshots}}/.keep
```

***Note**: Creating the `.keep` file in those directories will create some noise in your logfile, but doesn't appear to negatively affect anything else.*

Comment: Do you still lose other files/directories in `/usr/local/var/postgres`, such as `pg_clog`, `pg_stat`, `pg_subtrans`, `base`, etc...?

Comment: I did not, no.  I was only missing those three

Comment: In my case all the files that remained there were `postmaster.opts` and `server.log`. But thank you for the information.

Comment: May be due to removing and re-installing Postgres?

Comment: After re-installed postgres, everything looks fine. So I think it's due to the installation of Yosemite Beta.

Comment: I agree.  In my case it was only those three directories, but since I don't know why it's removing *any* directories, it's entirely possible it could remove others as well.

Comment: I had the exact same issue—this fixed it. Installation of GM Candidate (14A379a) over existing (and working) 10.9.5. The Yosemite installer must have removed these empty directories.

Comment: Reinstalling Postgres with Brew didn't recreate those directories. So, I had to follow Donovan's advice and create them by hand.

Comment: Just a suggestion for a more concise command: `mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp}/` and `touch /usr/local/var/postgres/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp}/.keep`

Comment: And this fixes PostG after installing Yosemite 10.10 release.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me on latest build of Yosemite and postgres 9.3.2 on

Comment: Thanks! Had the same problem after upgrading to Yosemite. Brew upgrade postgres didn't help.

Comment: You may not need to create all three directories (I only had to create two). Run `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start -w` to get better output when starting postgres. Then do `tail -5 /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` to see errors on startup. The errors will indicate which directories are missing.

Comment: Those .keep files actually cause me some grief in the server logs: `could not open temporary-files directory "pg_tblspc/.keep/PG_9.3_201306121/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory`

Comment: @infamouse Yes, I get those log entries too, but they don't trouble me.  If they bother you, you can remove the .keep files as are not strictly necessary.  They simply keep the directories from being accidentally deleted (since they're not empty).

Comment: I was also missing pg_snapshots and pg_stat directories.

Comment: @infamouse if the logs are annoying try chown-ing the .keep files and chmod-ing them so that the user that postgres runs as cannot see the files ( Note this might be impossible )

Comment: Thank you for this...I just upgraded to Yosemite this morning and, right on cue, PostgreSQL stopped working because apparently Apple just has to eff with non-OS-essential packages. I'm getting tired of every OS X upgrade being such a fiasco.

Comment: If you watch the Yosemite installer (Command-L while it is running and taking FOREVER!!) you will see it moving everything in /usr/local around furiously - no idea why, but I bet that empty directories get lost. How convenient!

Comment: In my case the .keep files should be directories, so I just executed this: `mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp}/.keep`

Comment: to start postgres i need to ran `pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/postgres/*`

Comment: I also had to create one extra directory 'pg_replslot'. Except that it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: experienced same as @Lucas for bottled postgres 9.4.0. I had to 
`mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp,pg_replslot}`

Comment: Experienced this, but had to run the following to get a server.log without warnings or errors: `mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp,pg_replslot,pg_stat,pg_logical/snapshots,pg_logical/mappings,pg_snapshots}/`. This is for brew postgresql 9.4.1

Comment: How do you get Postgres to automatically start when the system is rebooted?  It seems that everytime I restart my computer now after implementing your solution I need to run pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/postgres again to get everything working and I didn't need to do this before the upgrade to Yosemite.

Comment: Had to do the same after installing the latest version of postgres 9.4.5_2 on El Capitan. Your solution is still applicable. Works.

Comment: I had to add `/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_logical/snapshots` and `/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_logical/mappings` to start the server. (Yosimite, brew install homebrew/versions/postgresql94)

Comment: This worked great but I also had to create `pg_notify` - `mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_notify`

Answer (score 9):

[Donavan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1794315/donovan)'s answer is spot on, I just wanted to add that as i did different things with the database (e.g. `rake db:test`), it went looking for different directories that haven't been mentioned above and would choke when they weren't present, in my case `pg_logical/mappings`, so you may want to setup a terminal running:

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

and watch it for missing folders while you go thru your typical database activities.

Comment: Needed to add mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_logical/{snapshots,mappings}

Answer (score 6):

This is slightly off-topic but worth noting here as part of the PostgreSQL Yosemite recovery process.  I had the same issue as above AND I had an issue with PostgreSQL "seemingly" running in the background so even after adding directories I couldn't restart.  I tried using `pg_ctl stop -m fast` to kill the PostgreSQL server but no luck.  I also tried going after the process directly with `kill PID` but as soon as I did that a PostgreSQL process re-appeared with a different PID.

The key ended up being a `.plist` file that Homebrew had loaded...  The fix for me ended up being:

```
launchctl unload /Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql92.plist
```

After that I was able to start PostgreSQL normally.

Comment: My plist was named slightly differently:
`launchctl unload ${HOME}/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`
but basically that was also the same problem for me, and the same solution.

Answer (score 4):

The missing directories need to be present in your PostgreSQL data directory. The default data directory is `/usr/local/var/postgres/`. If you have set up a different data directory, you need to re-create the missing directories there. If you modified the homebrew-recommended `.plist` file that starts PostgreSQL, you can find the data directory there:

```
cat ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

(it's the `-D` option you started postgres with:)

```
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/postgres</string>
    <string>-D</string>
    <string>/usr/local/pgsql/data</string>
```

In the example above, you'd create the missing directories in `/usr/local/pgsql/data`, like so:

```
cd /usr/local/pgsql/data
mkdir {pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat,pg_stat_tmp,pg_replslot,pg_snapshots,pg_logical}
mkdir pg_logical/{snapshots,mappings}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with a dockerized Rails application.

Instead of pg_tblspc and other directories missing from /usr/local/var/postgres, they were missing from myRailsApp/tmp/db.

You will want to use a similar version of Donovan's solution, you will just have to alter to have the correct path for your Rails app...

```
mkdir /myRailsApp/tmp/db/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat,pg_stat_tmp,pg_replslot,pg_snapshots}/
```

Also, you will want to add a .keep file to make sure git doesn't disregard the empty directories.

```
touch /myRailsApp/tmp/db/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat,pg_stat_tmp,pg_replslot,pg_snapshots}/.keep
```

I noticed an error with a .keep in 1 of the directories, so just read the command line output carefully and adjust as needed.

Answer (score -20):

Creating the missing directories certainly works but I fixed it by reinititializing postgres db, this is a cleaner approach to avoid future problems.

**NOTE: This approach will delete existing databases**

```
$ rm -r /usr/local/var/postgres
$ initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Comment: Obviously deleting existing databases is not a minor exception here.  This a bit like saying "I couldn't find /var/tmp so I reinstalled the operating system."

Comment: Oh, man, this is "cleaner" than anything I can think of :) Just hope some random copy-paster from the interwebz doesn't shoot this directly into their console without looking at it :)

Comment: Sorry for the down vote Greg but I recommend rewording your solution to make it explicit that this approach should only be used in development or if the user can afford to wipe their DB.

Comment: Why is this downvoted so much? On a dev server this is the right way.

Comment: @JordonBedwell even on a dev server is bad idea, unless you are playing with a single app using db on your computer.. It's like "I can't start my favorite code editor, let's reinstall the OS"