# Mac OS Yosemite PostgreSQL

Tags: macos, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, osx-yosemite

I've just updated to Yosemite and my postgres version won't work, I'm receiving the following message from rails:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Even that I've started the server several times with

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

I'm trying to unlink postgreSQL from homebrew and reinstall, but I don't know if it will work.

Answer (score 16):

Just had to unlink postgreSQL

```
brew unlink postgresql
```

then

```
xcode-select --install
```

and finally

```
brew install postgresql

brew install openssl
```

But then rails server didn't work so:

```
rvm get stable
```

To see which was my current_ruby

```
rvm list

sudo rvm uninstall <current_ruby>

rvm install <current_ruby>
```

Now create initialize a postgredb

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres9.3.5
```

And start your server

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres9.3.5 -l logfile start
```

You're done.

Comment: Helpful. I had to recreate the folders mentioned in this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26001639/307308

Comment: You just made my life! I was missing the initdb step

Comment: Running `xcode-select --install` tells "me xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates"