# Why does brew doctor say XCode 6.0.1 isn't the latest version?

Tags: xcode6, homebrew, osx-yosemite

Just installed Yosemite and when I run brew doctor I get:

`Warning: Your Xcode (6.0.1) is outdated
Please update to Xcode 6.1.
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.`

But in the AppStore it looks like XCode 6.0.1 *is* the latest version. What's the best way to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

Tis that slight lag between 10.10 being Avail and xcode getting updated.   If you read the top of brew doctor output it says

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!
```

So if everything is working, then you should do what it suggests and ignore it.  The command line tools / compilers where updated for 10.10 (software update should have picked them up for you).   Are you running into any issues with compiling? or just that warning.

pulling up from the comments. Your ruby and postgresql issues are from the upgrade, but it isn't really brews fault, or that compiler error warning.

with rvm just reinstall your ruby.  My main dev is done with ruby-2.1.3 so

```
 rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.3
```

rebuilt ruby and all my gems.   The problem is that the ssl libs (maybe others) that ruby was linked to  were removed  / replaced in the upgrade to 10.10. The reinstall will rebuild and relink to the newer correct libs.

postgresql is slightly different.  Apparently during the upgrade a couple of empty directories in /usr/local/var/postgres get removed.  No idea why.

see this SO answer for how to fix that.

[`pg_tblspc` missing after installation of latest version of OS X (Yosemite or El Capitan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970132/pg-tblspc-missing-after-installation-of-os-x-yosemite-beta)

also if you are use pow (http://pow.cx)  you will need to upgrade it to the latest version as 10.10 removed ipfw completely and only leaves pf as the firewall. so you will need to the new version which uses pf anchors.

The above steps where all I needed to do it in order to get my dev back to working.

Comment: Yeah, everything is definitely not working. Basically everything related to RVM, Ruby, Rails, and Postgresql is busted after this Yosemite upgrade.

Comment: Postgresql is an easy fix. You can either reinstall or you create the missing directories.   With rvm just rvm reinstall your Ruby as the ssl libs it was linked to are missing.  I ran into the same issues.

Comment: If you show the exact errors that you are getting then we might be able to help.  I've successfully upgrade 4 macs to 10.10 all using. Rvm Ruby brew and postgresql and doing the above steps have everyting working as it was pre upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like developer.apple.com does show an XCode 6.1 as "Available Shortly" as of Fri, Oct 17, at 10pm central time. Not yet available from the AppStore. I guess I'm just too eager for an update.