# Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

I am trying to resolve this error but am unsuccessful and looked through some of the previous SO threads on this issue.

'sudo apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql-devel' did not work as I dont have apt-get. I tried replacing apt-get with wget and that did not work either.

I also tried the following but that did not work either and I got the error below

export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:$PATH
bundle install

An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Can anyone advise? I am on a Mac OSx V9.10.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution: Download the [postgresql.app](http://postgresapp.com):

Create or modify the `config/database.yml` file, adding the following [configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-postgresql-database):

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: name_of_app_development
  pool: 5
```

Comment: So I did that and now have a postgreSQL server running. But 'rails server' is still producing the same errors

Comment: Do you have the correct configuration in your `database.yml` file ?

Comment: Hmm..I don't think so. That seems to be my error, how do I fix this?

Comment: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@blablabla/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:105:in `database_configuration': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: (RuntimeError)
Could not load database configuration. No such file - /Users/user/Desktop/blablabla/config/database.yml

Comment: Hmm...I don't seem to have one. In my .gitignore file I have something that looks like this: 

# bundler state
/.bundle
/vendor/bundle/
/vendor/ruby/

# minimal Rails specific artifacts
db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal
/log/*
/tmp/*

# various artifacts
**.war
*.rbc
*.sassc
.redcar/
.sass-cache
/config/config.yml
/config/database.yml
/coverage.data
/coverage/
/db/*.javadb/
/db/*.sqlite3
/doc/api/
/doc/app/

etc etc...

Comment: I did not create this project, I am trying to work on it however. The above is the only mention of database.yml in my entire project

Comment: Ok, so that definitely seemed to get the rails server working. In terms of my project I am still having issues with it. I got prompted with an issue saying run 'bin/rake db:create' and then another issue that said run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development'

Currently I have the following error.

undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RegistrationsController:0x007fe36041d480>

Comment: Can you help explain what the issues are. I think you were definitely correct with creating a database.yml file, but now there seem to be completely different issues and for the most part the project should be working correctly

Comment: Actually this solved both your postgresql installation, and its configuration. You can run `rails c` to make sure the database is working fine. The new issue you got is different, please create a new question for that

Comment: What is in the file you posted? In particular: 
database: name_of_app_development
  pool: 5

Comment: This file includes the database configuration for all environments, I've posted only the development configuration, "database" is the name of your database (usually set as the name_of_the_app underscore environment. read more at about [Configuring a PostgreSQL Database](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-postgresql-database)

Comment: So do I need to change the name_of_app_development to be the name of my project?

Comment: yes, exactly. But this is local only on your device, so you can leave it as is.

Comment: Ok thanks for all of your help. I am starting another thread for the next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661659/undefined-local-variable-or-method-root-path-for-registrationscontroller0x0

Answer (score 1):

First you need install postgresql:

```
brew install postgresql
```

If you still get errors for missing paths, then check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970132/pg-tblspc-missing-after-installation-of-os-x-yosemite/26001639#26001639).

Comment: Ok I have definitely done this step and it seemed to be successful. I got this message so I"m assuming I had success: Warning: postgresql-9.3.5_1 already installed

Comment: This error occurs when I try to run rails server: 

/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@blablabla/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:105:in `database_configuration': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: (RuntimeError)

Comment: did you start the postgresql server `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` ?

Comment: You mean just run that before rails server? I typed in your command and got this: 

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2014-10-30 13:21:40 EDT
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

I then opened a new terminal tab and got the same error for 'rails server'

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is package manager for linux, not for mac. Use homebrew for MacOS. Instructions here http://brew.sh/

Comment: I have homebrew installed. I tried 'brew install pg' and 'brew install pgsql' Neither worked.

Comment: Try to completely remove postgres, and reinstall, as one one wise man shows in link, which I provided.

Comment: I ran bundle install and it shows pg 0.17.1 is included, and then I also see PostgreSQL is installed. However, 'rails server' is still leading to errors.