# Get this result back when putting `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` in terminal

Tags: postgresql, osx-yosemite

When I put `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` in terminal I get this back:

> LOG:  could not translate host name "localhost", service "5432" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
>      WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
>      FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets`

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: I had to clean up my etc/hosts file, there was a lot of mess there, then I was getting 
FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory,
 but this was easy to fix following this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970132/pg-tblspc-missing-after-installation-of-os-x-yosemite

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your /etc/hosts file for missing line:

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost

Regards

H